# Using “dependencies” in AngularJs json schema (version : draft-v4) Not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have this schema:

```
 {
      "title": "Test dependncies",
      "description": "This a test to show how we can use dependencies in json schema",
      "properties":{
          "graduate": {
              "title":"Graduate?",
              "type":"string",
              "enum":["Yes","No"],
               "options": {
               "dependencies":[
                  {"id":"minimumEligibilityAge","value":"Yes"},
                  {"id":"courseName","value":"No"}
                  ]
               }
          },
          "minimumEligibilityAge":{
              "id":"minimumEligibilityAge",
              "title":"Enter Age",
              "type":"number",
              "options":{"hide_display":true}
              },
          "courseName":{
              "id":"courseName",
              "title":"Enter Graduation Course Name",
              "type":"string"
          }
      },
      "type": "object"
    }
```

I am able to generate a form using [Angular-schema-form](https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form).

#### Expected behavior

**minimumEligibilityAge** & **courseName** shoud hide/appear depending on the value of properties. But it's not working & I have no Error.